# Fetch Multiple times per textinput in reactnative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

So bassically I am building a weather app in react native and using the weatherAPI for the weather API. So bassically What my issue is: let's say that I searched the weather for New York and it gave me 80F and I searched up the weather for Dallas BUT it gives me the same details as New York's weather.

I know that my API is getting called once but How can I make my APIcall multiple times as per as my textinput changes?
Here is the code:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  weatherText: "Enter",
  isLoading: true,
  locationData: [],
  currentData: []
};
```

}

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.apiCALL()
 }



apiCALL(){
     return fetch(
       `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=???&q=${this.state.weatherText}`//I took out the key on purpose.
     )
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         this.setState({
           isLoading: false,
           locationData: responseJson.location,
           currentData: responseJson.current,
         });
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error);
       });
  }
```

Note: I took out the key to the API on purpose.

So How can I achieve this. Like I said before How can I call the API as the Textinput changes?
Am I suppose to use `ComponentDidMount` or is there some other built-in function/method in order to achieve this?.

Comment: You can call it inside you componentDidUpdate by comparing the state value or even in the text inputs onTextChange still calling it for each change it a bit too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the api on `componentDidMount`, call it when the text input changes or on a submit button beside a text input.
Say you have `TextInput`, use

```
<TextInput placeholder="eg. New York" onChange={(val)=>this.apiCALL(val)}/>
```

and modify the `apiCALL` as

```
apiCALL(city){
  return fetch(
    `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=???&q=${city}`//I took out the key on purpose.
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        locationData: responseJson.location,
        currentData: responseJson.current,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Now this function is reusable and can be used for all the cities.

Comment: This might be a dumb question: What is the difference between onChangeText and onChange

Comment: yes. use onChangeText instead. It is the right way. You can refer the difference here https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange.
And regrding the error, since all this code runs async, it fetches `this.state.currentData["condition"]["text"]` even before it would be ready. SO use this instead of it. `this.state.currentData && this.state.currentData["condition"] && this.state.currentData["condition"]["text"]`. So it uses the value only when it is available.
Also, show some upvote to the answer please.

Comment: It saying undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSourceCurrent["temp_f"]') I tried ur code but it's not working

Comment: Use the same logic of && in the above comment.

Comment: Thank You but the apiCALL is not working like it's not changing from New York to Dallas

Comment: `<TextInput
              style={styles.textInputStyle}
              onChangeText={(weatherTxt) =>
                this.textInputFunc(weatherTxt) && this.API_CALL(weatherTxt)
              }
            />` This is what I put that you told me to put but it's not working






`API_CALL = (city) => {
       console.log(city)
   fetch(
     `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=???&q=`+city
   ) //There is more code down below Just did not put it`

Comment: what does this.textInputFunc do? Just put the complete code on react js fiddle or so and share the link

Comment: this.textInputFunc just does updates what ever I write to the state

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Thank You so much you code helped a lot